# Using parametrized thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to create some number of threads which would be equal to `nOfplayers`.
I'm doing it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nOfPlayers; i++)
{
    thr[i] = new Thread(
        () => playerComm[i].Communicate(handler[i], ref game, ref table));
    thr[i].Start();
}
```

There is only one time I use this cycle. But somehow, I don't know why, `new Thread` executes more than `nOfPlayers-1` times. So I've got the index out of the range.

Does anyone know why it does it happen and how to do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's executing the right number of times - but you're capturing `i`, which is incrementing before the thread gets to use it.

Create a copy of `i` in your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nOfPlayers; i++)
{
    int player = i;
    thr[i] = new Thread(
        () => playerComm[player].Communicate(handler[player], ref game, ref table));
    thr[i].Start();
}
```

See Eric Lippert's ["Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) blog post for more info.

Also, using `ref` in multiple threads like this feels wrong to me - are you sure you need `ref` parameters at all? See [my article on parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for details about what it means.

Finally, given that you appear to have two collections here - one for handlers and one for communicators, consider having a single collection instead, where each element of the collection knows about both parts.

Then in C# 5 you could get away with:

```
// Only correct in C# 5 and later!
var threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (var player in players)
{
    // HandleCommunications would call comm.Communicate(handler, game, table)
    var thread = new Thread(() => player.HandleCommunications(game, table));
    thread.Start();
    threads.Add(thread);
}
```

Note that in C# 3 and 4 you'd still need an extra local variable within the loop, but the behaviour of `foreach` with respect to variable capture was fixed to be rather more sensible in C# 5.

Comment: One of these days I'll be able to remember and spot variable capture by eye without ReSharper telling me instead. Until that day, +1 to you, sir.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Well I'm not saying I'd have spotted it if I'd just been reading the code without context... but with the context of "my threads seem to be doing the wrong thing" it's an obvious thing to check :)

Comment: Thank you. That is really interesting.

Comment: Yes I thought about that to make it with list. Considering to ref. Well yes, I think that maybe it's wrong. But I'd like to modify game and table with my Communicate methods. So  for me It seems the way to do it. Thank for your advices:)

Comment: @user3149474: Do you mean you want to change the variable's value, or change data within the object that the variable's value refers to? The latter seems more likely to me. You should really make sure you understand the difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, I want to change data within an object. Thank you again:)